# floodFill inverted fill

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, flood-fill

Edit: i just want to change black pixel outside hull to white while keeping the black pixel inside hull.

```
contours, hierarchy = cv.findContours(morph, cv.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    mask = np.zeros_like(frame)

    
    for hull in [cv.convexHull(cnt) for cnt in contours]:
        cv.drawContours(mask, [hull], -1, (255, 255, 255), -1)

   
    inverted= cv.bitwise_not(mask)
    k = cv.bitwise_or(mask, inverted)

    return k
```

[image: example] [image: result]

just like this example img, i want to change the outside of hull to white and keeping the black inside it. Like the image above. But when i tried it show all white pixel and the black pixel inside hull also get white

Comment: Just invert your mask (or change the background and fill colors)

Comment: @fmw42 already to do that but the black dot inside hull also get white pixel. I remove the cv.floodfill to this:
`inverted=  cv.bitwise_not(mask)
k = cv.bitwise_or(mask, inverted)
return k`

Comment: What i mean is just change the color outside hull to white while keeping the black pixel inside hull

Comment: Change your colors. Create a white background image to start (use np.full_like()), then draw a black filled contour.  See https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.full_like.html

Comment: Floodfill with white from first black pixel.